USPEX variable compostion structure search does not move to the next generation
I am doing a variable composition structure search with 2 different elements, however the USPEX simulation only works for first generation and gets stuck at "Calculating fitness" stage.
This issue does not happen when I do a normal structure search using only one element.
Can anyone please advise on this?
For input files, I am using the files given in Ex31, and also reducing population size and number of generations in each population.
Thanks
